# Invalid Date - Error on "MM/YYYY" string to Date conversion

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I am trying to convert a string to Date, but I am getting a `Invalid Date` error.

The input would be a String containing one of the following data formats:

- **`YYYY`** only year
- **`MM/YYYY`** month & year
- **`DD/MM/YYYY`** full date

The expected output is a `Date` type, however, the only format I cannot convert is **`MM/YYYY`** one.

How could I solve this specific case? Thanks.

Comment: You could read up on [Javascript date parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js), or look at a library such as [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following code:

```
@Input() initialDate: any; //Either "YYYY", "MM/YYYY" or "DD/MM/YYYY"
@Input() mask: string = 'text' //Either "full", "month" or "year";

ngOnInit() {
  // Handle initialDate value
  this.setInitialDate();
}

private setInitialDate() {
  if (this.initialDate) {
    switch (this.mask) {
      case 'full':
        this.day = this.initialDate.getDate().toString();
        this.month = this.months[this.initialDate.getMonth()];
       this.year = this.initialDate.getFullYear().toString();  

      break;
    case 'month': 
      let monthYear = this.initialDate.split('/');
      if (monthYear.length == 2) {
        this.month = this.months[monthYear[0] - 1];
        this.year = monthYear[1];
      }

      break;
    case 'year': 
      this.year = this.initialDate;

      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}
```